# WordPress Cascade Deleting doesn't work

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I need some help with databases. 
Ok, i am creating 2 tables like those:

```
CREATE TABLE inventory_category ( 
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE inventory_subcategory(
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    category_id int NOT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY  (category_id) REFERENCES inventory_category(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

As you can see, `category_id` references `inventory_category id`.
So, as i can understand, when i will delete something in `inventory_Category`, his child in the `inventory_subcategory` will be automatically deleted? 
But it doesn't works. Why?

Comment: I have not kept up with MyISAM in a while but I believe you need to be using InnoDB if you want the database to handle that for you. If MyISAM can do that now, apologies.

Comment: It workes! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked Mysql.com and it looks like foreign keys are not supported with MyISAM for MySQL or MariaDB.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html

However the Innodb engine may be what you want:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html